# Cacls recursive wildcard

Tags: windows, file-permissions, users

I have a user named `foo` and I want him to have only read permission over all files and folders in folder `D:/bar`

Inside the folder I have a lot of folders and there are `.dbf` files scattered.

I want to give read and write permission for the `*.dbf` files to the user `foo`, but only read permission for this user to all the other files and folders within `D:/bar`.

How can I do that using calc or icalcs?

**EDIT:** It could be a batch script too, if necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
icacls D:\bar /grant:r foo:(oi)(ci)r

icacls D:\bar\*.dbf /t /grant foo:m
```

(/grant:r to replace existing perms)

Comment: Only one problem, is that you are granting, so you are giving more permissions. In the first command I want to give **only** read permission. Then **grant** modification over .dbf

Comment: ok, I found out: is `/grant:r`. Editing accordingly